# Find object in datetime range

Tags: django, django-models

Let's assume that I have modeL;

```
class MyModel(...):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    stop = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have also two records:

> 1. start=2012-01-01 7:00:00 stop=2012-01-01 14:00:00
> 2. start=2012-01-01 7:00:03 stop=2012-01-01 23:59:59

Now I want to find the second query, so start datetime should be between start and stop, and stop should have hour 23:59:59. How to bould such query?

Some more info:

I think this requires F object. I want to find all records where start -> time is between another start -> time and stop -> time, and stop -> time is 23:59:59, and date is the same like in start

Comment: You have hard changed your question with new requirement: "time is 23:59:59, and date is the same like in start"

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) and [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
from django.db.models import Q
q1 = Q( start__range=(start_date_1, end_date_1) ) 
q1 = Q( start__range=(start_date_2, end_date_2) )
query = (''' EXTRACT(hour from end_date) = %i 
         and EXTRACT(minute from end_date) = %i 
         and EXTRACT(second from end_date) = %i''' % 
         (23, 59,59)
        )

MyModel.objects.filter( q1 | q2).extra(where=[query])
```

Notice: Posted before hard answer requirement changed 'time is 23:59:59, and date is the same like in start'

Answer (score 0):

To perform the query: "start datetime should be between start and stop"

```
MyModel.objects.filter(start__gte=obj1.start, start__lte=obj1.stop)
```

I don't quite understand your second condition, though.  Do you want it to match only objects with hour 23:59:59, but for any day?

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = '2012-01-01 8:00:00'
stop_hour = '23'
stop_minute = '59'
stop_sec = '59'

where = 'HOUR(stop) = %(hour)s AND MINUTE(stop) = %(minute)s AND SECOND(stop) = %(second)s' \
        % {'hour': stop_hour, 'minute': stop_minute, 'seconds': stop_ec}

objects = MyModel.objects.filter(start__gte=dt, stop__lte=dt) \
                         .extra(where=[where])
```